# psycopg2 sql.SQL: Composed elements must be Composable

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import datetime


def connect(conn):
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    # create a cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

    col_names = sql.SQL(', ').join([
        sql.Identifier('lookup'),
        sql.Identifier('LOL1'),
        sql.Identifier('LOL2'),
        sql.Identifier('identifier1'),
        sql.Identifier('identifier2'),
        sql.Identifier('timestamp_first_entry'),
        sql.Identifier('timestamp_last_entry'),
        sql.Identifier('some_number')
    ]),

    values = sql.SQL(', ').join([
        "hash",
        [  # LOL1
            [[1.0, 2.0],  # list of lists of lists 1.1
             [3.0, 0.5]],
            [[-1.0, -2.0], # list of lists of lists 1.2
             [-3.0, -4.0]]
        ], [  # LOL2
            [[1.0, 2.0],  # list of lists of lists 2.1
             [3.0, 0.5]],
            [[-1.0, -2.0], # list of lists of lists 2.2
             [-3.0, -4.0]]
        ],
        "identifier1",
        "identifier2",
        datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10),
        datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12),
        20
    ])

    query_base = sql.SQL("insert into {table_name}({col_names} values ({values}))".format(
        table_name=sql.Identifier("raw_orderbook"),
        col_names=col_names,
        values=values
    ))

    cur.execute(query_base)

    cur.close()


# https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database="test",
        user="ian",
        password="")

    connect(conn)
```

results in an error of

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/panthera/src/database/tester.py", line 73, in <module>
    connect(conn)
  File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/panthera/src/database/tester.py", line 33, in connect
    values = sql.SQL(', ').join([
  File "/home/ian/anaconda3/envs/panthera/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/sql.py", line 288, in join
    return Composed(rv)
  File "/home/ian/anaconda3/envs/panthera/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/sql.py", line 109, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Composed elements must be Composable, got 'lookup' instead
```

Given that `composable` is the base class, I'm not really sure what the error is because of. As far as I know it *seems* correct based on the examples from the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). My `sql_schema`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "raw_orderbooks";
CREATE TABLE "raw_orderbooks"
(

    lookup                text, -- essentially our lookup key comprising: hash(exchange_pair_timestapOfFirstEntry)
    LOL1                  DOUBLE PRECISION[][][],
    LOL2                  DOUBLE PRECISION[][][],
    identifier1                  text,
    identifier2            text,
    timestamp_first_entry TIMESTAMP,
    timestamp_last_entry  TIMESTAMP,
    some_number       int
);
```

one other idea I had was to wrap the non-datetime values in `sql.Literal` but then I run into the datetime issue.

Looking around, I've seen other people using different notation but it feels less "clean" which is definitely subjective but IDK.

## Edit

Based on the comments from the answer, my updated script is

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import datetime


def connect(conn):
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    # create a cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

    col_names = sql.SQL(', ').join([
        sql.Identifier('lookup'),
        sql.Identifier('LOL1'),
        sql.Identifier('LOL2'),
        sql.Identifier('identifier1'),
        sql.Identifier('identifier2'),
        sql.Identifier('timestamp_first_entry'),
        sql.Identifier('timestamp_last_entry'),
        sql.Identifier('some_number')
    ]),

    values = sql.SQL(', ').join([
        "hash",
        [  # LOL1
            [[1.0, 2.0],  # list of lists of lists 1.1
             [3.0, 0.5]],
            [[-1.0, -2.0], # list of lists of lists 1.2
             [-3.0, -4.0]]
        ], [  # LOL2
            [[1.0, 2.0],  # list of lists of lists 2.1
             [3.0, 0.5]],
            [[-1.0, -2.0], # list of lists of lists 2.2
             [-3.0, -4.0]]
        ],
        "identifier1",
        "identifier2",
        datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10),
        datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12),
        20
    ])
    table_col_names = ['lookup','LOL1','LOL2','identifier1','identifier2','timestamp_first_entry','timestamp_last_entry','some_number']

    col_names = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in table_col_names )

    place_holders = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(table_col_names ))

    query_base = sql.SQL("insert into {table_name} ({col_names}) values ({values})").format(
        table_name=sql.Identifier("raw_orderbook"),
        col_names=col_names,
        values=place_holders
    )

    print(query_base.as_string(conn))
    cur.execute(query_base,values)

    cur.close(
```

but I'm still running into the issue `TypeError: Composed elements must be Composable, got 'lookup' instead`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sql.SQL.join`](http://%5Bhttps://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.join%5D) join a sequence of `Composable`  but you are providing normal variable like string , list etc in `values` variable.

secondly i will suggest use `placeholder`  for values in query then pass `values` to execute .

```
table_col_names = ['lookup','LOL1','LOL2','identifier1','identifier2','timestamp_first_entry','timestamp_last_entry','some_number']

col_names = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in table_col_names )

place_holders = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(table_col_names ))

query_base = sql.SQL("insert into {table_name} ({col_names}) values ({values})").format(
        table_name=sql.Identifier("raw_orderbook"),
        col_names=col_names,
        values=place_holders
    )

print(query_base.as_string(conn))
cur.execute(query_base,values)
```

Comment: Interesting. So, the actual values are only used in the `cur.execute`? I guess I just got confused by `a %s-style placeholder` from the docs and thought that I needed to have `%s` in it.

Comment: actually  values can be pass in `execute` or you have to use `sql.Literal ` instead of `sql.Identifier` like `values_ = sql.SQL( ' , ').join( sql.Literal(n) for n in values)`

Comment: Sorry, having made the modifications (I've pasted the updated script above), I'm still running into `TypeError: Composed elements must be Composable, got 'lookup' instead`

Comment: So, the second method (sql.Literal) works but I could not get the first to work. I'm still marking this as completed and accepting your answer. Thank you for your help!